# A term to describe a thick jacket as confining

Tags: single-word-requests

What would one call a jacket or some other piece of uncomfortable yet protective heavy-duty clothing that restricts the wearer's movements due to its confining heaviness?

> He wanted to release himself from the __ windbreaker.

Comment: You more or less answered this yourself. _He wanted to release himself from the restrictive windbreaker._

Comment: @JoeDark thanks so far. I thought there might be a term that particularly applies to clothing

Comment: not a single word, but you could say 'protective yet restrictive'. I don't think you'll find a single word to encompass everything you want to say.

Comment: Tight is the right word which means [allowing little or no room for free motion or movement](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tight)

Comment: *Confining* is perfect IMO, just use that.

Comment: How about restrictive?

Comment: Just a note, but a *windbreaker* is a decidedly light and non-restrictive type of a jacket.  It would never be described as "uncomfortable yet protective heavy-duty clothing" From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windbreaker): *A windbreaker is a thin coat designed to resist wind chill and light rain, a lighter version of a jacket. It is usually of light construction*"

Comment: @Jim thanks, I always thought it was some type of heavy winter jacket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL:DR - I should have edited the title to ask for a word to describe those jackets that make you look like the Stay Puft Marshmallow Man, instead I wrote this:

> (E.g.) He wanted to release himself from the *hindrance* of the windbreaker but he knew that to do so would mean his death.

**hindrance** /ˈhindrəns/ noun: something that provides resistance, delay, or obstruction to something or someone. –[Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hindrance%20definition)

> (E.g.) He wanted to release himself from the *hindering* windbreaker but he knew that to do so would mean his death.

**hindering** adjective: preventing movement; from **hinder** hin·der (hĭn′dər) verb –[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hinder)

> To obstruct or delay the progress of: *a snowfall hindered the mountain climbers; lack of funds that hindered research.*
>
> To interfere with action or progress.

Synonyms: hamper, impede, obstruct, encumber

> **These verbs mean to slow or prevent progress or movement.**
>
> *To hinder* is to hold back or delay, as by barring the way forward: *The unfair performance review threatened to hinder her career.*
>
> *Hamper* suggests the imposition of restrictions or limitations: *"He was a little hard of hearing; it hampered him in learning"* (Oliver La Farge).
>
> *To impede* is to slow by making action or movement difficult: *"[The] wagon proceeded down the street at a slow walk, impeded by the crush of curiosity seekers"* (Stephen O'Connor).
>
> *Obstruct* implies the presence of obstacles: *Passage of the bill was obstructed by a filibuster.*
>
> *To encumber* is to weigh down, as with complications or difficulties: *"[King] Leopold particularly envied the Hapsburgs because, unlike him, they were little encumbered by parliaments and constitutions"* (Adam Hochschild).

See also, **inhibit**: hinder, restrain, or prevent (an action or process). –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=inhibit&oq=inhibit&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1398j1j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) (and as mentioned in comments: restrictive)

> (E.g.) [Inhibited; restrained; restricted; hindered; hampered; impeded; obstructed; encumbered] by the bulky windbreaker, he found it difficult to get a fire going.

Although it is included in the last example, *bulky* does not alone convey the idea that this is "heavy-duty clothing that restricts the wearer's movements", nor does it have to be so, to do so. E.g., stiff leather aprons; armor; gloves, etc.

If you're looking for a term to describe *modern* (usually down-filled, polyester) windbreakers (as opposed to the real kind that are ankle length and have a storm flap: [oilskin dusters](https://www.google.com/search?q=oilskin+duster&oq=oilskin+duster&aqs=chrome..69i57.140754j1j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)), *bulky* is spot on - otherwise, not so much.

Comment: Hinderance is not the same as confinement.

Answer (score 6):

*He wanted to release himself from the **bulky** windbreaker.*

bulky:

1. of relatively large and cumbersome bulk or size.
2. (of a fabric or yarn) thick; lofty.
3. (of a garment) made of thick, resilient fabric or yarn.

([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bulky))

Comment: *Bulky* is what it is, not why it is [verb/adjective].

Comment: Bulk does not equate to confinement.

Answer (score 4):

*Cumbersome* - "Difficult to handle or use especially because of size or weight" ([WordWeb online](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/CUMBERSOME))

Answer (score 4):

How about **constrictive**/**constricting**?

It emphasises that you can't move freely as a result of wearing the item and as such I think it's a great match for what you're trying to say.

Comment: Strange that this isn't the accepted answer: I came here to offer this, and it's the obvious match!

Answer (score 3):

"He wanted to release himself from his **straitjacket** windbreaker".

- Literally, a straitjacket is a garment made of strong material and
  designed to bind the arms, as of a violently disoriented person.
- Figuratively, it's anything that severely confines, constricts, or
  hinders.

Comment: This was what popped into my mind, too.

Answer (score 2):

"Unwieldy" is a possible candidate. [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unwieldy) defines the word as;

> (Of an object) difficult to move because of its size, shape, or weight

Tight seems to be the perfect word, though. Please see the above comment.

Comment: Tight just means tight, not heavy or protective or heavy-duty.  I much prefer unwieldy and cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if **stifling** might do here?

[Google (Oxford Dictionaries) gives it as](https://www.google.com/search?q=stifling%20meaning&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

> making one feel constrained or oppressed.

and **stifle** as

> make (someone) unable to breathe properly; suffocate.
>
> "she stifled him with a pillow";
>
> airless, suffocating, oppressive ...

I suggest this word because I think it describes the garment adequately, but does a better job at giving the *feeling* one might have wearing an oppressive jacket, which I think is what the OP was after:

> He wanted to release himself...

Comment: Oppressive could be better than stiffling as an answer.